# deactve asset_host configuration Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I run different environments for production, staging and review. They are identical, except for the asset_host.  I would like to clear the asset host setting, but not sure how.

How do I deactivate the asset_host setting that was already set in production?

```
require Rails.root.join("config/environments/production")

Rails.application.configure do
  # Each beta server gets its own asset environment
  config.action_controller.asset_host = config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'Nothing"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the configuration from `config/application.rb` and instead make a separate configuration file in `config/environments/{ENV_NAME}.rb` with environment-specific settings. The default value for `asset_host` is nil, so you really only need to make a `config/environments/production.rb` file and set it to your value there.